# Set autoincrement value for ALL tables in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, alter

Is there a way I can set an autoincrement value for all the tables in my database to be (say) 1001 rather than 1.   My DB has tens of tables, I want to set all the auto-increment fields to start from 1001

I don't want to go and do an alter table query on each table.. I'm looking for a QUICK and easy way to alter all the tables?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you don't want to run a SQL query?

Comment: SQL is fine, but set auto0increment for all (tens of tables) to 1001

Answer (score 0):

Run this SQL Query: ALTER TABLE NameOfTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;

It will start the count from 1000.

Comment: This is answering the wrong question. I want to modify for ALL tables. My DB has tens of tables, I want to set all the auto-increment fields to start  from 1001.

Comment: So you want all tables to start from 1001?